Exclude property from SELECT but Include in INSERT and UPDATE in Entity Framework Core
In Entity Framework Core, I have an entity class with a property that I want to exclude from SELECT operations but still include during INSERT and UPDATE. The entity class cannot be modified, so I can't add backing fields or make changes to the class itself. How can I configure this property to be ignored when querying data, but still allow it to be set and updated when saving changes?
The entity class looks like this:
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}

I need MyProperty to be omitted when the entity is loaded from the database, but still included in INSERT and UPDATE operations.
Note that I cannot use a solution like this:
var myEntities = context.Set<MyEntity>()
    .Select(e => new MyEntity
    {
        Id = e.Id,
        // Exclude MyProperty
    });

because I don't know the exact entity and property in advance. This custom configuration is needed to replace an old custom in-house ORM that used a custom attribute [WriteOnly]
For old ORM [ReadOnly] attributes, I successfully retrofitted the logic with the following:
propertyBuilder.Metadata.SetBeforeSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore); // Avoids inserting the property
propertyBuilder.Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Ignore); // Avoids updating the property

I thought to Ignore the property in OnModelCreating:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
        .Ignore(e => e.MyProperty);
}

and overriding the SaveChanges method to force the property being modified:
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<MyEntity>())
    {
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added || entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            entry.Property(nameof(MyEntity.MyProperty)).IsModified = true;
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}

This effectively prevents the property from being materialised during SELECT, but the entry.Property(nameof(MyEntity.MyProperty)).IsModified = true; line cannot work as the property MyProperty is no longer part of the model
If it helps, all my entities inherit from a base class that can be customized.

I have no idea, how you can do that, maybe via TableSplitting, where you can define another entity for the same table record. And why you cannot use Select?

Properties can be private and set in a constructor. They will be read, but at least they won't be visible. Or use shadow properties.

Thanks for the replies! However, as I mentioned in the question, is there a solution that doesn't involve modifying the entity class or adding backing fields?
If it helps, all my entities inherit from a base class that can be customized.

For querying data, you may use dynamically generated Select projection, but these entities will be detached and useles for updating. So basically EF Core do not support your scenario.

I suggest having two properties. One public being part of your business model and one private used for persistence (I used attributes to configure the model, but of can of course use the fluent API instead)
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private string _myProperty;

    [NotMapped]
    public string MyProperty {
        get => _myProperty;
        set {
            _myProperty = value;
            MyPropertyDb = value;
        }
    }

    [Column("MyProperty")]
    private string MyPropertyDb { get; set; }
}

The point is that setting MyProperty will write to its backing field as well as update MyPropertyDb. Getting the value will only retrieve the backing field and ignore the value of MyPropertyDb which might have been read from the DB.

I'm not saying this is the best solution but I think this may help you out. We can modify the query with interceptors to not query for the column. If @olivier-jacot-descombes solution works or fulfils your need. I think then it's better to stay away from modifying the sql query.
public class RemoveColumnInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    private readonly string _columnToRemove = "MyProperty";

    public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(
        DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
    {
        if (command.CommandText.StartsWith("SELECT", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // Modify the SELECT command to exclude the specified column
            command.CommandText = RemoveColumnFromSelect(command.CommandText, _columnNameToRemove);
        }

        return base.ReaderExecuting(command, eventData, result);
    }

    private string RemoveColumnFromSelect(string sql, string columnName)
    {
        // Use a regular expression to locate and remove the specific column from the SELECT clause
        string pattern = $@"\b{columnName}\b\s*,?\s*|\s*,?\s*\b{columnName}\b";
        return Regex.Replace(sql, pattern, "'xx-xx' as MyProperty" // ""-- you can simply remove this also
        , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
}


Register your interceptor
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>((serviceProvider, optionsBuilder) =>
{
    optionsBuilder
        .UseSqlServer("YourConnectionString")
        .AddInterceptors(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RemoveColumnInterceptor>());
});

Important Considerations 

Testing: Test this interceptor thoroughly, as altering SQL statements dynamically may lead to unexpected behavior.
Edge Cases: The regular expression used may need adjustments for complex queries (like joins or subqueries).
Ensure the application doesn’t rely on this column in any part of the application logic, as excluding it in SQL queries will make it unavailable.

By following this approach, you’ll be able to consistently exclude a specific column from all SELECT statements in EF Core using interceptors.
